# How to solve ambiguous reference to overloaded definition in scala

Tags: scala

I am getting the following error in scala:

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method register in trait Configurable of type (x$1: Any, x$2: <repeated...>[Class[_]])javax.ws.rs.client.Client
and  method register in trait Configurable of type (x$1: Any) javax.ws.rs.client.Client
match argument types (Object)

[ERROR]     client.register(ClientFilter.getFilter().asInstanceOf[Object])
```

Shouldn't asInstance[Object] inform the compiler which version  of jersey client register to use?  Here's the code:

```
val client: Client =
      ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .build();
 client.register(ClientFilter.getFilter().asInstanceOf[Object])
```

ClientFilter.getFilter() is an instance of ClientRequestFilter

Comment: You're hitting https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2991

Comment: One of the workarounds might also be using a method without varargs, such as `public C register(Object component, int priority);` from `javax.ws.rs.core.Configurable`. Like this `.register(new SomeFilter, 1)`

Comment: @rpozarickij Even better.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a Java class to do the dispatch for you, due to [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2991) not getting resolved in favor of my PR, which added `-Yno-java-tupling` to do what you expect. Hopefully the workarounds will be temporary, and won't be necessary once overload resolution precedes autotupling, as described in a comment on the ticket.